# Solve the non-linear system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, rational-functions, symmetric-functions

For real $x,y,z>0$ solve the system of equation

\begin{cases}
 \dfrac{1}{x}-3 y+4 z=5,\\
   \dfrac{1}{y}-4 z+5 x=3,\\
      \dfrac{1}{z}-5 x+3 y=4,
\end{cases}
It is easy to check out that
$$
x =\frac 1 5, y= \frac 1 3,  z=\frac 1 4
$$

is a solution.

How I could  prove that there is no any other real solutions?

Edit.  By adding all equations we get 
$$
\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=12.
$$

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to compute $S$-polynomials from the given polynomials, namely
$$
25x + 9y + 16z - 12=0, \\
24yz + 16z^2 - 32z + 5 =0.
$$
Then we can eliminate $x$ and $y$ and substitute into the three original equations. We obtain
$$
(64z^3 - 80z^2 - 52z + 5)(4z - 1)=0.
$$
Although we have all roots real here, we see that the only positive real solution is the one given above.

Comment: Yes, but I want to do it more  elementary without the Groebner basis theory

Comment: Computing an $S$-polynomial is elementary. You do not need a Gröbner basis.

Comment: Ok, I will try, Thank you

Answer (score 3):

eliminating $y,z$ we get for $x$:
$$125 x^4-60 x^3-58 x^2+18 x=1$$

Comment: How did you eliminate it?

Comment: You can always eliminate other variables when your number of equations are same as number of variables . but here it was little cumbersome.

Comment: Usual elimination -express $y$ from first equation and substitute into other equations and so on doesnt work here. Need a trick.

Comment: We need a trick, or some general idea (for example, $S$-polynomials).

Answer (score 2):

Multiply the first equation by $5x$, the second by $3y$, the third by $4z$. Then add all three up. This gives you $25x + 9y + 16z = 12$. Now this is clearly a useful intermediate result. For example, you can substitute it into the original equations to eliminate one variable. This yields six new relations:

[1] $4/x -25x - 21y = 8$;

[2] $3/x + 25x + 28z = 27$

[3] $5/y - 9y - 36z = 3$

[4] $4/y + 9y + 45x = 24$

[5] $5/z + 16z + 24y = 32$

[6] $3/z - 16z - 40x = 0$

From eqs. $1$, $3$ and $6$ we obtain these bounds: $0 < x < \frac {2}{5}$; $0 < y < \frac {1}{3} \sqrt{5}$; $0 < z < \frac {1}{4} \sqrt{3}$.

Eliminating $y$ from eqs. $1$, $4$ [or alternatively $z$ from eqs. $2$, $6$] yields a fourth order equation for $x$. In the same way fourth order expressions for $y$ and $z$ can be derived.